# git: update remote repository with my new files

Tags: git, github

I am a newbie with git/github and working on a automation testing project. Although I am familiar with the basic git commands and have also read many articles on it, the commands used and when they are used, I am not confident of applying them on a real time project in my company.

So there is a remote repository with the folder structure:

```
Folder 1
    Folder 2
       Folder 3
          TC1
          TC2
          TC3
```

so the TC(testcase files automation) are in Folder 3. Folder 3 is in Folder 2 etc. This is the entire front end project structure.

I cloned this repository locally. Created a branch called my-sample-tests.
Then I created a new TC(testcase file), say TC6.
So this is where I am at:
I did:

```
$git add .
$git commit -m  "file TC6"
```

```
$git status
On branch my-sample-tests
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/my-sample-tests' by 432 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

What should be my next steps if my code should be on the remote git along with the other test files.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: What did the message from git say? `use "git push"`. Use it.

Comment: There's something odd above: if you ran `git commit` once, you should be `ahead of` the upstream branch by *1* commit. The above says `ahead ... by 432 commits`: more than four hundred too many.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have **`committed`** your changes to your **`local working directory`**. In order to push these changes to the **`remote repository`** that is hosted on the github, you need to push these files or technically speaking **`commits`** by doing a:

```
git remote push origin
```